# Sourcetree won't load or install after a Windows 10 update

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

My Sourcetree was working perfectly, then Windows 10 did a large update. Now, Sourcetree won't launch at all, and the installer seems to crash after a few seconds.

What can I do to get it working again?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer This is a self-answered question.

Comment: Sure, and thank you for posting it. However, the guidelines for posting self-answered questions are the same as for questions seeking answers. (I would say that on that basis, the question could do with some startup logs, since it is probably not very answerable at present. However I appreciate you probably cannot get that information now you have fixed it).

Comment: It took me quite a time to fix this. In my case this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556235/4190858

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

This is related to invalid dictionary files being detected on launch. See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7898 for the gory details.

#### Fix

All you need to do is install some version 2.1.X of Sourcetree from https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/download-archives, say "Yes" when prompted to delete the temporary dictionary files, then reinstall your desired version of Sourcetree. This fixes the problem for version 2.2.X and 2.3.X.